# What does "Security Group" when creating a new environment means?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, administration, power-platform

We want to create a new power platform environment, and we are asked to define a Security group, as follow:

[image]

So what is the purpose for this security group? so only members inside this group will be able to create new solutions ? and edit existing solutions? or this also include the users who will be using the solutions' power apps and power automate? in other words if i define only the admin-group to have access to the environment through the above security group, then does this mean that other non-admin users will not be able to access and use the power apps inside this environment even if the power apps was shared with them?

Answer (score 1):

When you associate the Power Platform environment with a security group, only the members of security group will be added as "Users" for the environment. You can see the "Users" from environment details page:

1. From the Microsoft Power Platform admin center, select the environment to which you want to add users.
2. Select **Settings** > **Users + permissions** > **Users**.

**Source**: [Add users to an environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/add-users-to-environment)

You'll see the list of users that have already been added to the environment.

---

Also, note:

> - If a security group is associated with an environment, only users with Dataverse licenses or per app plan that are members of the environment security group will be created as users in the environment.
> - If you don't specify a security group, all users who have a Dataverse license (customer engagement apps such as Dynamics 365 Sales and Customer Service) or per app plan will be added to the new environment.
> - All licensed users, whether or not they are members of the security groups, must be assigned security roles to access data in the environments. You assign the security roles in the web application. If users don’t have a security role, they'll get a data access denied error when trying to run an app. Users can't access environments until they are assigned at least one security role for that environment.

**Sources**:

1. [Control user access to environments: security groups and licenses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/control-user-access)
2. [Create and manage environments in the Power Platform admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/create-environment)

---

In your case, if only the admin-group is associated with the environment then only the members of admin-group will be added to the environment. Then you can share the Power Apps applications and Power Automate flows with the users of admin-group.

If you want to add other group members to the environment, you should be able to do it manually by following: [Add users to an environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/add-users-to-environment)

Comment: thanks for the useful reply, so if we have some power apps inside this environment that need to be shared with all users, then we will need to add all users to the environment's security group? if the answer is yes, then will all users have the ability to create apps and edit existing apps inside the environment ?

Comment: If you want all users in your company to be added inside the environment, don't assign the security group with the environment. Select "None" option against the security group while creating the environment. Also, not everyone will have ability to create new apps unless the [necessary role (Environment Maker or higher) is assigned to them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/database-security) and edit existing apps unless they are shared with user as co-owner of the individual app.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so if i do not select any security group, then can i restrict this later on?

Comment: Yes, check this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/control-user-access#associate-a-security-group-with-an-environment

Comment: Hi @microsoftdeveloperdesigner, does this answers your question? please mark it as an answer if it helps you in any way.